# One Drive stuck - cannot delete folder and never fully synced

Tags: windows-10, sync, onedrive

I have setup OneDrive Sync for Documents, Desktop and Pictures.
Later I disabled Desktop.
Now I cannot get fully synced and cannot delete old renamed Desktop folder.
Why I cannot delete a folder? OneDrive seems completely stuck.

[image: OneDrive]

Comment: A folder not fully synchronized typically means it contains a file that cannot be synchronized. Are you able to delete the folder from within the browser?  What error do you receive when you attempt to delete the folder?

Comment: @Ramhoud no error, delete file in explorer just does nothing. Found out there are errors on disk also, so it was one reason probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File system got corrupted during OneDrive sync. I did scan disk for errors and fix the errors during Windows startup. That was the reason that delete file/folder in explorer not worked probably. I had reinstalled OneDrive to latest version and it reported bad filenames and did not let me synchronize the Documents folder at all.

I very much recommend to upgrade OneDrive to the latest version & to review long paths and illegal characters in filenames before enabling sync of existing Windows folders.